# How can I write like this example and boxs in latex

Tags: environments, boxes, examples

[image]

How can I write like this example and boxs in latex
thanks very much

Comment: Hard to give you a precise answer without more details : are the boxes of fixed width ? Will there be multiline text in one of them ? You can start looking for `\colorbox`and `\color` from package `xcolor`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Take a look at the tcolorbox package

Comment: Do you consider this question answered?

Answer (score 9):

This could be a starting point :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{green!30!black!90!white}{\makebox[3cm][l]{\strut\color{white}\sffamily\textbf{Example 20-1}}}%
\colorbox{green!30!black!20!white}{\makebox[10cm][l]{\strut\color{green!30!black!90!white}\sffamily\textit{Theoretical...}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much but I want auto counter example

Comment: @moh bitar look for `\newcounter` and `\stepcounter` in any LaTeX manual or introduction. Furthermore, you'll want to define an environment for that : `\newenvironment`. Give us a precise description if you want more help, you're letting us guess far too much.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `titlesec` for keeping up with counter automatically. Then you just issue `\subsection`, like you are used to, and the header will print, with the counter there. Of course, you can change this to say, `\paragraph`, er even create your own, `\example`, all with support for referencing and such.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,calc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\ExampleLine}[2]{%
\makebox[0pt][l]{{\color{#1}\rule[-1ex]{#2}{4ex}}}}
\titleformat{\subsection}%
    [block]% Shape
  {}% Format
  {\ExampleLine{YellowGreen}{\textwidth}\ExampleLine{OliveGreen}{2.8cm} {\color{white}Example: \thesection \alph{subsection}}}% Label
  {.6em}% Sep
  {\bfseries\itshape \hspace{0.2em}}% Before-code
  %[]% Aftercode

\begin{document}
\chapter{Some examples}
\section{The most important section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Theoretical }
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much but I want auto counter example

Comment: @mohbitar see my edit